# one codeigniter controller named site needs to handle multiple domains

Tags: codeigniter, routes, multiple-domains

Got a controller in codeigniter who handles different sub sites.

- `site/index/1` fetches content for subsite A
- `site/index/2` fetches content for subsite B

Now we decided to register domain names for these sub sites.

so what we need:

```
http://www.subsite1.com  -> default controller should be site/index/1
```

without the `site/index/1` in the URI.

```
http://www.subsite2.com  -> default controller should be site/index/2
```

without the `site/index/2` in the URI.

I fiddled and tried to play with `routes.php` but getting nowhere..
Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

in your routes.php file you need to set this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'http://www.subsite1.com' ? "site/index/1" : "site/index/2");
```

and if your trying to force it somewhere when some weird url is types in:

```
$route['404_override'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'http://www.subsite1.com' ? "site/index/1" : "site/index/2");
```

and for the second one just switch it to 2

Comment: with a switch statement? like switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){

Comment: I would just use a short hand if statement if your trying to switch it like that.  Or just use a regular if statement, set the result to a variable, and assign the variable. See my edit.